# Code first: Database only created after execute certain code?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to create a database using code first.
And my database is always in "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" mode.

I notice that, if I don't try to execute some query against the database, such as

```
using (var db = new Models.TnHContext())
        {
            var query = from u in db.Users
                        select u;
            foreach (var u in query)
            {
                txt += u.UserID + "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

the database won't be created. Unless I execute it, only I can see the database created. Wonder if this is due to EntityFramework design/default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [database initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is called when you execute a query against the context, retrieve the [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) from the [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), or call [the `Database.Initialize` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Therefore, if you want to create the database immediately without executing a query, you should use:

```
context.Database.Initialize(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Database initialization is triggered lazily by Entity Framework. It will only occur when EF tries to connect to the database. You can manually trigger database initialization using the following.

```
using (var db = new Models.TnHContext())
{
    db.Database.Initialize(force: false);
}
```

Setting the force parameter to false tells EF not to run initialization if it has already been triggered.