# MVC Code First - Database not generating

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am developing a MVC application using Code First Approach. I have defined my model classes in a separate class library project. I have also defined my DBContext class. I have ensured that my DBContext class has the same name as my Connection String. For some reason , I am not seeing the database created. I understand is by defining your classes and connection string, Entity framework would generate the database. I am sure with my connection string as it works fine with my other applications. Could somebody tell what the problem is

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
 public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

App.Config class

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=XYZ-PC\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=SalesOrderManagement;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Which version of EF?

Comment: it is the latest. 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

EF won't generate the database until you call the context. You can insure this by adding a static constructor with your selected initializer:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{

    static TestDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestDbContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesnt recognise EntityModelContext(). Did you mean static TestDbContext as consructor

Comment: Yes, it's a constructor. Edited.

Comment: I built the project but it dosent seem to create the database

Comment: Yes, you need to access your context to trigger the lazy creation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303710/code-first-database-only-created-after-execute-certain-code

Comment: public TestDbContext()
            : base("name=TestDbContext")
        {
            
         Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TestDbContext>());
         Database.Initialize(false);
        
        }

Comment: Is there anything that I am missing. I have been googling a lot to find a solution. I didnt expect this too be so difficult

Comment: Are you calling the context anywhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109276/discussion-between-tom-and-steve-greene).